# How can i get book's title and author's firstname into the same result table when my database is designed like this

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have 3 tables
1. titles table have 2 fields(title,isbn)
2. authorisbn table have 2 fields(authorid,isbn)
3. authors table have 2 fields(authorid,firstname)

so i want to get a book's title(where the title is like '%Java%') and author's firstname of that book to fill in the same result table
what is the sql statement should i have to use to achieve that

my sql statement is like this

```
select titles.title, titles.isbn, authorisbn.authorid   
from titles inner join authorisbn 
where title like '%Java%' and authorisbn.isbn = titles.isbn
```

but it does not work because i can get only authorid

sorry for my english im learning it as well

Comment: Sir, I didn't understand you, please be more specific and explain, if you can't with language, make a simple graph with paint software or anyting but just let us understand what you want

Comment: Okay wait, I will try it for you

Comment: im trying to edit my post so it will easier to understand but there are errors .it said i need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links

Comment: Wachirawit, your description of what you have is very sloppy. For example, you say a table has 3 fields but you only list 2 fields.  (Letting aside the fact that in any language that I know or ever even heard of, we separate numbers from words with a space.) We will need to see SQL CREATE TABLE statements.  Also, you will need to define what a "result table" is, because it is not a standard term.

Comment: Also, on websites like stackoverflow.com, "it does not work" is not considered to be a legitimate description of a problem.  Not even close.  It actually tends to be frowned upon.  Please explain ***precisely*** what you expected to receive, and ***precisely*** what you received instead.

Comment: result table is the table that contain result from  select statement 


sorry, im trying to add pics to the post but i cant. there are some error and i am new for this site.trying to fix my post

Comment: You may be learning English but you need to also learn to format the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your answer:

```
 select v1.title, v1.isbn,authorisbn.authorid, authors.firstname 
 FROM books v1
 INNER join authorisbn
 ON v1.isbn = authorisbn.isbn
 INNER JOIN books v2
 on v2.isbn = authorisbn.isbn
 INNER JOIN authors
 WHERE v2.title like '%Java%';
```

[image]

Here, v1 and v2 are representing the books table, but when we use it multiple times in our query we should define them in new variables.

If this helps, please check it as an answer

Comment: I just found out that I can join more than 2 tables
and this is want I want.I applied your code to fit my purpose and it work fine,thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select titles.title, titles.isbn, authorisbn.authorid, authors.firstname
from authorisbn
left join titles on titles.isbn = authorisbn.isbn
left join authors on authors.authorid = authorisbn.authorid
where titles.title like '%Java%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get to the authors table to get authors.firstname

```
select titles.title, titles.isbn, authorisbn.authorid, authors.firstname   
  from titles  
 inner join authorisbn 
    on authorisbn.isbn = titles.isbn 
   and title like '%Java%' 
 inner join authors 
    on authors.authorid = authorisbn .authorid
```

can move title like '%Java%' down into a where clause

```
where title like '%Java%'
```